# Appending a list in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I don't know how these two things are working, and their outputs. And if there is any better way to do the same work.

Code 1:

```
A = []
s = []
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    s.append(name)
    s.append(score)
    A.append(s)
    s = []
print(A)
```

Output 1:

```
[['firstInput', 23.33],['secondInput',23.33]]
```

Code 2:

```
A = []
s = []
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input()) 
    s.append(name)
    s.append(score)
    A.append(s)
    s.clear()
print(A)
```

Output 2:

```
[[],[]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected list behavior. Python uses references to store elements in list. When you use append, it simply stored reference to s in A. When you clear the list s it will show up as blank in A as well. You can use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) method if you want to make an independent copy of the list s in A.

Comment: Seeing the first code, I have a question in my mind. Why didn't the 9th line in the code have any noticeable effect on the output?

Comment: You created a new list with same name when you used `s = []`. When you used clear you changed the value of the list you had stored inside A. The first method is also not recommended as it can cause unwanted behavior

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways to do this, but you don't need list `s` at all.

```
A = []

for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())

    A.append([name,score])

print(A)
```

Comment: and what about the first and second output?

Comment: The output will depend on `input`. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you are appending list "A" with list "s", it creates a reference of "s" in "A", that's why whenever you are calling the `.clear` method on "s" it clears the elements from "A" as well.

In code 1 you are intialising a new list with the same name "s", everything works fine.

In code 2 you are calling the `.clear` method on "s" which creates a problem.

In order to use code 2 and get the expected result, you can do this:

```
A = []
s = []
for i in range(0,int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input()) 
    s.append(name)
    s.append(score)
    A.append(s[:])    # It copies the items of list "s"
    s.clear()
print(A)
```

Or you can do without "s" as answered by BenT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` to get your result:-

```
A = [ [ x for x in input("Enter name And score with space:\t").split() ] 
    for i in range(0, int(input("Enter end range:\t")))]
print(A)
```

**Output**

```
Enter end range:    2
Enter name And score with space:    rahul 74
Enter name And score with space:    nikhil 65
[['rahul', '74'], ['nikhil', '65']]
```